# How to keep my BCC in MFMailComposeViewController as readonly in iphone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I am creating a project in which my app users can send mail within my app. While users sends each mail to their friends, i want that mail to send to my mail . so i added my mail in BCC. But the problem is user can easily delete my mail in BCC. I want my BCC to be not deletable .

I used the following code to send mail

```
MFMailComposeViewController* controller = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
controller.mailComposeDelegate = self;
[controller setSubject:@"4 Frax"];
[controller setMessageBody:@"Hai dude" isHTML:NO]; 
[controller setBccRecipients:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"office@4Frax.com"]];
if (controller) [self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
[controller release];
```

Can anyone please tell me how to avoid user from deleting my mail in BCC.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can't, there is no API available to do this. Since this is a privacy issue. Apple will not allow you to get the user e-mail  (or let them mail you it) without expres permission from the user.

Thus the mail composer will not allow you adjust, hide and fields. You can only prefill it.

Comment: In my case, i will get user permission to send bcc to my mail. When he agrees that, heis not allowed to change edit the BCC. Is it possible?

Comment: No, like I stated in my answer: "You can't, there is no API available to do this."

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that's a nice way to treat your users... but if you *really* want to do it I think your only option is to set up your own mail server and route your message through that. As [rckoenes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11948383/2998) notes, there is no API to do it on iOS.